# Apple Music Migration

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music, apple-music

**What’s the most efficient way to replicate my Apple Music library on a different account?**

I was thinking of creating a playlist with all my library and then sharing this playlist with the other account, however adding the tracks to the playlist seems like a very manual process and I have over 4000 tracks in my library.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the first song in your library. 
Scroll down and shift-click on the last song in the library. 
Now everything is selected. 
Two-finger tap on any of the songs to show the context menu 
Select “add to playlist”.